# How to identify the cause of 100% CPU percentages of app service plan in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans, stackify

I have deployed 12 app services on Azure, all of which are under a single App Service Plan (P1v3). I've noticed that the CPU usage spikes up to 100% four times a day, and I'm looking to understand the root cause of these spikes and find a solution. If anyone has insights or suggestions, please share them.I also check the stats in application insight and stackify as well but nothing find any calls which causes that issue..

Answer (score 1):

In order to check the cause behind **CPU utilization** the best option is to check the, ***Diagnose and Solve Problem tab*** in your Azure Web app like below:-

[image]

Refer this [**Blog**](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/10/05/Diagnose-App-with-High-CPU.html) **By** **Ellie Alume** for more details in getting insights into CPU utilization.

Another option is to enable Diagnostic Logs and store the logs in either Azure storage account or send it to Log analytics workspace like below:-

[image]